# Mongoose delete nested subdocuments and documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have:

```
    let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
passwordHash: {type: String, required: true},
fullName: {type: String, required: true},
salt: {type: String, required: true},
ads: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'}],
roles: [{type: String}]
```

}

```
let adSchema = mongoose.Schema({
author: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
title: {type: String, required: true},
category: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true},
town: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Town', required: true},
```

}
);

```
let categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
ads: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'}]
```

}
);

```
let townSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
ads: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'}]
```

}
);

I want to find for example town by id and remove all ads in it(and ofcourse to remove the ads from their categories and authors).How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest bulk getting the array of object Ids and using it like this:

```
Ad.remove({_id: {$in: Ad_ids_array}}, function(){...}); // and so on
```

You can add a pre-remove hook in the ad schema definition like this:

```
adSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  let lethis = this;
  // Pull ad out of all the Category docs that reference the removed ad.
  this.model('Category').update({}, { $pull: {ads: lethis._id}}, { safe: true }, next);

  // Pull ad out of all the User docs that reference the removed ad.
  this.model('User').update({}, { $pull: {ads: lethis._id}}, { safe: true }, next);
});
```

This will remove the ad from the categories and users that have it in their ads array.